# ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 9994 elements, new values have 1 elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

I got an error with the following function:

```
def function(df,column,value): 
    df=df.set_index([column]).filter(regex=value, axis=0)
    return df

function(df,[column],'xyz')
```

Error:

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 9994 elements, new values have 1 elements

NOTE: I have to fix the function. I cant use a different solution.

Comment: Consider using ``` instead of ` for multiline code, and changing the title for a more comprehensive description of the exception, instead of copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
df.set_index(column)
```

Because right now you are passing second argument as a list.

Comment: Can you provide sample from df? Because I created simple df and the code worked just fine.

Comment: I have fixed it...Thanks a lot

Comment: I saw your edit in the original question. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hahaha yeah :).... I realized that I havent changed my code  as you said. Then, I have changed it and it has worked... I really appreciate your helping :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Then maybe you can accept the answer as a accepted answer :)